# Extended properties для нескольких серверов

Tags: sql, sql-server, запрос

Добрый день!
Нужен Ваш совет, я добавил в Managment Studio группу локальных серверов(Local Server Groups) теперь пытаюсь вытащить расширенные опции, для определенной базе на сервере работает а вот для всех не получается, нужна помощь что еще нужно добавить для выгрузки.
Это работает правильно выгружает

```
    SELECT name, create_date
FROM sys.databases ;
GO
```

А вот это:

```
    SELECT *
FROM sys.extended_properties
GO
```

или это

```
 SELECT name, value 
    FROM sys.extended_properties;
    GO
```

Выдает пустоту

Comment: Еще есть мысль, но нужны дельные советы по реальности реализовать следующее: Взять данные БД и серверов sys.databases и собрать их в массив, после сделать цикл по use [массив[итерация]] для sys.extended_properties

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решилось созданием временной таблицы и для кириллицы тип nvarchar

```
EXEC sp_msforeachdb 
'INSERT INTO #properties SELECT ''?''  AS DatabaseName, 
 CAST(name AS nvarchar), CAST(Value AS nvarchar) 
 FROM [?].sys.extended_properties WHERE class=0'
```

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понимаю. То вам необходимо выполнить запрос сразу на множестве серверов, которые вы добавили в Local Server Groups. Для этого вам необходимо на корневой папке (Local Server Groups) или на любой другой, созданной дополнительно, нажать правую кнопку мышки и выбрать "New Query" ("Новый запрос" на Русском). После этого у вас откроется окно запроса как обычно, но если вы посмотрите на нижнюю часть этого окна, то оно будет красным и слева-снизу будет указано к какому количеству серверов вы подключены. Например "Connected (12/12)". Теперь те запросы что вы будете выполнять в этом окне, будут транслироваться на все сервера и вы получите результаты с каждого из них.

Прилагаю скриншот:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Да все правильно, я так делаю 15 из 15 подключено. Проблема в том, что вышеуказанный скрипт по выводу информации(Extended Properties) не работает, в рамках какой то базы скрипт корректный, а на все сервера и базы не транслируется.

Comment: Думаю вам поможет команда sp_msForEachDB, которая позволяет выполнить любой код на каждой БД на сервере. Предполагаю что вот то, что вам нужно:  
 SELECT name, create_date FROM sys.databases
 GO
 sp_msForEachDB @command1= 'USE [?];
 SELECT DB_NAME()   
  SELECT name, value FROM sys.extended_properties;'

Comment: Проверил, ход понятен, только одна проблема USE [?], здесь я не могу указать конкретную базу их много и нужно чтобы по всем проходил SELECT, можно ли собрать в массив первую часть и числом перебрать базы?

Comment: Так USE [?] как раз позволяет перейти в нужную БД